# Iterating over dataframe and using replace method based on condtions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am attempting to iterate over a specific column in my dataframe.

The column is:

```
df['column'] = ['1.4million', '1,235,000','100million',NaN, '14million', '2.5mill']
```

I am trying to clean this column and eventually get it all to integers to do more work with. I am stuck on the step to clean out "million."  I would like to replace the "million" with five zeros when there is a decimal (ie 1.4million becomes 1.400000) and the "million" with six zeros when there is no decimal (ie 100million becomes 100000000).

To simplify, the first step I'm trying is to just focus on filtering out the values with a decimal and replace those with 5 zeros.  I have attempted to use np.where for this, however I cannot use the replace method with numpy.

I also attempted to use pd.DataFrame.where, but am getting an error:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i,'column'] = pd.DataFrame.where('.' in df.at[i,'column'],df.at[i,'column'].replace('million',''),df.at[i,'column'])

``AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Im sure there is something I'm missing here. (I'm also sure that I'll be told that I don't need to use iterrows here, so I am open to suggestions on that as well).

Comment: what about 'mill' then?

Comment: Why are you using a for loop for this?

Comment: @AMC it's my natural instinct when looking to iterate over a df with conditions, though I'm seeing with the answers below that a for loop is unnecessary and time-consuming.

Comment: @AdamA _it's my natural instinct when looking to iterate over a df with conditions_ Gotta work on those instincts, then! You should take a look at the Pandas docs, I find them quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample data - it looks like you can strip out commas and then take all digits (and `.` characters) until the string `mill` or end of string and split those out, eg:

```
x = df['column'].str.replace(',', '').str.extract('(.*?)(mill.*)?$')
```

This'll give you:

```
         0        1
0      1.4  million
1  1235000      NaN
2      100  million
3      NaN      NaN
4       14  million
5      2.5     mill
```

Then take the number part and multiply it by a million where there's something in column 1 else multiple it by 1, eg:

```
res = pd.to_numeric(x[0]) * np.where(x[1].notna(), 1_000_000, 1)
```

That'll give you:

```
0      1400000.0
1      1235000.0
2    100000000.0
3            NaN
4     14000000.0
5      2500000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['column'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('million','00000'))
```

Make sure your dtype is string before applying this

Comment: Why would you not use the operations provided by Pandas?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the issue had been that some of the cells with "million" needed 5 zeros and some needed 6 zeros.

Answer (score 0):

For the given data:

```
df['column'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).split('m')[0])*10**6
                   if 'million' in str(x) or 'mill' in str(x) else x)
```

If there may be many forms of million in the column, then regex search.